# Grouping to find min,max for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

This would be relatively easy if I only cared about a single min and max for each group, the problem is my requirement is to find the various boundaries.  An example data set is as follows:

```
BoundaryColumn  GroupIdentifier
1                  A
3                  A
4                  A
7                  A
8                  B
9                  B  
11                 B  
13                 A
14                 A
15                 A
16                 A
```

What I need from the sql is a result set as follows:

```
min  max  groupid
1    7    A
8    11   B
13   16   A
```

Essentially finding the boundaries for each cluster of the groups.

The data would be stored in either oracle11g or mysql so syntax can be provided for either platform.

Comment: How can you determine which GroupIdentifiers go together? For example, you've got two "A"s in your desired output.  Is there some other column you can group on?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

A disclaimer: It's a lot easier to query partial results and process something like this with a front-end language. That said...

The following query works for Oracle (which supports analytic queries) but not for MySQL (which does not). There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ce46/15).

```
WITH BoundX AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
     BoundaryColumn,
     GroupIdentifier,
     LAG(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLag,
     LEAD(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLead
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY BoundaryColumn
  )
  WHERE GIDLag IS NULL OR GroupIdentifier <> GIDLag
     OR GIDLead IS NULL OR GroupIdentifier <> GIDLead
)
SELECT MIN, MAX, GROUPID
FROM (
  SELECT
    BoundaryColumn AS MIN,
    LEAD(BoundaryColumn) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS MAX,
    GroupIdentifier AS GROUPID,
    GIDLag,
    GIDLead
  FROM BoundX
)
WHERE GROUPID = GIDLead
```

Here's the logic, step by step. You may be able to improve on this, because I get the feeling there's one subquery too many here...

This query pulls the prior and following `GroupIdentifier` values into each row:

```
SELECT
 BoundaryColumn,
 GroupIdentifier,
 LAG(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLag,
 LEAD(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLead
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY BoundaryColumn
```

The result looks like this:

```
BoundaryColumn  GroupIdentifier  GIDLag  GIDLead
1                  A                         A
3                  A                A        A
4                  A                A        A
7                  A                A        B
8                  B                A        B
9                  B                B        B
11                 B                B        A
13                 A                B        A
14                 A                A        A
15                 A                A        A
16                 A                A
```

If you add logic to get rid of all the rows where `GIDLag` = `GIDLead` = `GroupIdentifier`, you'll end up with the boundaries:

```
WITH BoundX AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
     BoundaryColumn,
     GroupIdentifier,
     LAG(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLag,
     LEAD(GroupIdentifier) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS GIDLead
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY BoundaryColumn
  )
  WHERE GIDLag IS NULL OR GroupIdentifier <> GIDLag
     OR GIDLead IS NULL OR GroupIdentifier <> GIDLead
)
SELECT
  BoundaryColumn AS MIN,
  LEAD(BoundaryColumn) OVER (ORDER BY BoundaryColumn) AS MAX,
  GroupIdentifier AS GROUPID,
  GIDLag,
  GIDLead
FROM BoundX
```

With this addition the results are:

```
MIN MAX GROUPID GIDLAG GIDLEAD
--- --- ------- ------ -------
  1   7 A              A
  7   8 A       A      B
  8  11 B       A      B
 11  13 B       B      A
 13  16 A       B      A
 16     A       A
```

Finally, include only those rows where `GroupID = GIDLead`. That's the query at the top of this answer. The results are:

```
MIN MAX GROUPID
--- --- -------
  1   7 A
  8  11 B
 13  16 A
```

Comment: Complex but best answered.

Comment: What about if there is only one item in a group, for instance if you remove all but the first A value?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this site regarding "runs" of data: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data

Armed with the knowledge provided in that link, you could write a query like this:

```
SELECT BoundaryColumn,
GroupIdentifier,
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table T
WHERE T.GroupIdentifier <> TR.GroupIdentifier
AND T.BoundaryColumn <= TR.BoundaryColumn
) as RunGroup
FROM Table TR
```

Using this information, you could then group by "RunGroup", and select the GroupIdentifier and min/max BoundaryColumn.

EDIT: I've felt the peer pressure, here's an SQLFiddle with my version of the answer: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/9a24c/4/0

Comment: Will that work without some sort of date value or such, to compare to (like AND G.GameDate <= GR.GameDate in the article)?

Comment: In this example, it looks like the BoundaryColumn will play the role of the GameDate. I edited my answer with a clearer example

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that they were sequential.  If they really are, that should work very nicely.

Comment: @Tom whoops, missed a line while copy-pasta-ing from notepad :) query corrected

Comment: That makes it a little clearer.  The alias in the main `FROM` s/b "TR", correct?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, yes, I'm in a food coma from lunch

Comment: Sorry my mistake, but not the answer.

Comment: @RajeshPaul this query alone will not hand-feed you the answer, but it will provide the necessary structure to do what the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach(Oracle). Here we simply divide result set returned by the query issued against table `t1`(your table) into logical groups(`grp`). Each new group starts when a value of `GroupIdentifier` changes:

```
select min(q.BoundaryColumn)  as MinB
     , max(q.BoundaryColumn)  as MaxB
     , max(q.GroupIdentifier) as groupid
  from ( select s.BoundaryColumn
              , s.GroupIdentifier
              , sum(grp) over(order by s.BoundaryColumn) as grp
           from ( select BoundaryColumn
                       , GroupIdentifier
                       , case 
                           when GroupIdentifier <> lag(GroupIdentifier) 
                                                   over(order by BoundaryColumn) 
                           then 1
                         end as grp
                    from t1) s
       ) q
 group by q.grp
```

Result:

```
      MINB       MAXB  GROUPID
---------- ----------  -------
         1          7  A       
         8         11  B       
        13         16  A
```

[**SQLfiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bf63/2)